# Wildfly-8.1 Hibernate jars Conflicts with my own jars

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly-8

When i migrated from `jboss-6.3-eap` to `wildfly-8-1` i saw following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.classmate.types.ResolvedRecursiveType cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.classmate.types.ResolvedObjectType
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._resolveSuperClass(TypeResolver.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._constructType(TypeResolver.java:395)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._fromClass(TypeResolver.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._fromAny(TypeResolver.java:299)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._fromParamType(TypeResolver.java:437)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._fromAny(TypeResolver.java:305)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeResolver.java:409)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._constructType(TypeResolver.java:395)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._fromClass(TypeResolver.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableHelper.instanceMethodParametersResolveToSameTypes(ExecutableHelper.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableHelper.overrides(ExecutableHelper.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableHelper.overrides(ExecutableHelper.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.accepts(ExecutableMetaData.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataImpl$BuilderDelegate.add(BeanMetaDataImpl.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataImpl$BeanMetaDataBuilder.addMetaDataToBuilder(BeanMetaDataImpl.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataImpl$BeanMetaDataBuilder.add(BeanMetaDataImpl.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getOrCreateBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.isConstrained(BeanMetaDataManager.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:171)
```

My application works fine in jboss-6.3-eap and all hibernate configurations are ok. my hibernate jars are (i haven't classmate jar in my libs):

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-3.6.7.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-pi-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
```

I think that this exception has generated because some of my jars conflicts with wildfly jars, and i cant prevent wildfly from loading its default hibernate jars.

Comment: would you please provide more info?

Comment: [Some tips on using Hibernate in JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final](http://planet.jboss.org/post/some_tips_on_using_hibernate_in_jboss_as_7_0_0_final) did you try to setup a suitable deployment-structure.xml? Check out [How to Use Hibernate 3 in an Application](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/hibernate3) as well.

Comment: My application works fine in jboss-6.3-eap and all hibernate configurations are ok.

Comment: This basically means you are loading the same class from two different sources(jars). Ie, classloading/classpath issue.

It's highly likely you and wildfly are loading different versions of similar jars (ie, hibernate). Fix your dependencies so you are only using one version of each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception was generated because wildfly hibernate-validator library was newer than my app hibernate-validator, so i resloved problem by adding following line in jboss-deployment-structure.xml exclusion section in my application:

```
<exclusions>
 <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
  .
  .
  .
<exclusions>
```